# What is the max value for onRmsChanged in RecognitionListener

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm implementing voice to text in android. I want to provide feedback to the user the same way google does with there voice to text. Some type of indication as the sound level dips and peaks

I have values that are coming in on onRmsChanged. In order to map this to a progress bar with a max value of 100 I need to know the max value for onRmsChanged.

But it's not stated anywhere?

How can I show sound level feedback without knowing the max value?

```
class listener implements RecognitionListener {
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
        }

        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged " + rmsdB);
        }

        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
        }

        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
        }

        public void onError(int error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error " + error);

        }

        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);

        }

        // Called when partial recognition results are available.
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
        }

        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be overcomplicating things a little.

The value is a float, so theoretically the maximum possible value is [Float.MAX_VALUE](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE)

The value of the float is generated by [the new RMS dB value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onRmsChanged%28float%29).

Information on [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)

Information on [dB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)

I feel that all you are concerned with is interpreting the volume level to the user? Therefore just pick a scale of quiet, medium and loud and adjust the UI accordingly.

```
    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(final float rmsdB) {

        float quiet_max = 25f;
        float medium_max = 65f;

        if (rmsdB < quiet_max) {
            System.out.print("Quiet" + rmsdB);
            // quiet
        } else if (rmsdB >= quiet_max && rmsdB < medium_max) {
            System.out.print("Medium" + rmsdB);
            // medium
        } else {
            System.out.print("Loud" + rmsdB);
            // loud
        }
    }
```

By adjusting the level of your voice during testing you should be able to establish what the thresholds of quiet, medium and loud should be. Don't forget to test on multiple devices though, as this may vary by device hardware. Although, it shouldn't vary so much as to mess up the visual feedback you want to provide.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This definitely helps but the issue is I could find the quiet, medium level for a giving device but not for the rest. So if I pick quiet_max=25 then for some other device even the loudest input could be less < 25

Comment: @stack - The scale is an example. You should watch the values in the logcat and establish what you think they should be. Only if the device is faulty and incorrectly reporting the sound levels will there be great variation.

Comment: So since this is a normalized version for sound the values should pretty much be about the same across devices if all is OK with the device.

Comment: @stack - In theory, 'yes'. But you should prove and determine this for yourself by watching the logcat output for multiple devices.

Comment: And don't forget to test with multiple versions of Android and multiple different speech recognizers... Using the Google recognizer on Android 4.1.2 I see values between -2 and 10 in the logcat.